# Convert walk animation in place

Tags: animation, graph-editor

So, take a 24-frame walk cycle where, instead of animating the character walking in place, you animate  them actually moving forward. The first frame and the last frame are identical except for the fact that the last frame is further down the Y axis than the first one. Normally, looping this animation would make it jump back to the original pose. However, using a Cycles modifier with "Repeat with Offset" enabled on every Y transform parameter would make the animation constantly move forward as it loops.

The benefits to this is, instead of having to imagine what the character's movement would be as they waddle in place, I can see them in actual motion. No more guessing at how the feet should move to avoid sliding. It also makes non-constant motion, like a limp or some other behavior that would make the character move slower at some points than others, pretty easy to do.

However, the main drawback to this is that it's no longer really usable as a walk cycle in the NLA editor or anything.

So what I would like to do is, essentially, bake the opposite of what the "Repeat with Offset" modifier is doing. **Press a button, and all the selected bones' keyframes are modified so that the forward-moving animation becomes locked in place like a traditional walk cycle**. I suppose technically this would be linearly editing the Global Y transform of each bone on a per-frame basis (on frame 1 it moves it back 1 unit, frame 2 it's 2 units, frame 5 it's 5 units, etc.).
Non-constant motion would, consequently, look like the character is sliding backward and forward from time to time to account for, well, the fact that it's not constant motion. (Think as if you had a camera following the walking character at a constant rate. Even though they're moving a fixed amount every 24 frames, the spacing within those 24 frames is uneven and so they look as if they fall behind ever so briefly every loop.)

Is there a way to do this? It can be a little more complicated than just one click of a button if it has to be, if it requires some complex constraint space-switching or whatnot. Certainly would be nice if it could be simple, though.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, you could parent your armature to an empty, move the empty forward each 24 frame with a constant interpolation, and give a Repeat with Offset to this empty so that it continues indefinitely?

Comment: There's actually a new plugin for doing exactly this
[In Placer](https://www.blendernation.com/2021/11/09/in-placer-a-free-blender-addon-to-make-your-animation-in-place/)

Comment: @moonboots That would work, except it isn't affecting the actual animation. If there was a way to bake that motion to the actual keyframes such that the rig did not need to be parented to the empty after the operation, that would be perfect.

Comment: @pacchu I'll take a look at that!

Comment: @pacchu it looks like the addon is extremely limited right now, so unfortunately I don't think that'll solve it...